# How do I resize all images using PIL and maintaing ratio?

Tags: python, image-resizing

I have a Folder named /Gallery/ and it has subfolders with lots of images in it and i need to resize it all with a width of 800px.

How can I automate the process I'm using this code:

```
from PIL import Image

basewidth = 800
img = Image.open('imagename.jpg')
wpercent = (basewidth/float(img.size[0]))
hsize = int((float(img.size[1])*float(wpercent)))
img = img.resize((basewidth,hsize), Image.ANTIALIAS)
img.save('imagename.jpg')
```

to do something like 
for each picture in each folder in gallery
   rezizepicture

Thank you!.

Answer (score 0):

for Python 3.5+

```
import glob    
from PIL import Image

for infile in glob.glob("/Gallery/**/*.jpg", recursive=True):

    basewidth = 800
    img = Image.open(infile)
    wpercent = (basewidth/float(img.size[0]))
    hsize = int((float(img.size[1])*float(wpercent)))
    img = img.resize((basewidth,hsize), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    img.save(infile)
```

Comment: This code will not return the files in any of the subfolders.

Comment: I change it to "/Gallery/*/*.jpg" to iterate over files in subfolders

Comment: `"/Gallery/*/*.jpg"` will miss files in the top level directory, that's why I used [Path.rglob()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.rglob).

Comment: ("/Gallery/**/*.jpg", recursive=True) will catch flies in the top level directory

Answer (score 0):

You can use os.listdir(path) to get all the files in a directory, and os.path.join(directory, fileName) to get the entire path to a file. Then use a loop like "for fileName in os.listdir(directory):" to loop through all the file in the directory. You may want to add a check to ensure you are only operating on JPG files. Inside the loop, use your already written code as a start. I wouldn't overwrite the existing images, unless you have them backed up somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

To iterate through the files matching a specific pattern you can use globs in [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#module-pathlib). Here's an example that identifies all of the files with a `jpg` extension in all sub directories.

```
>>> import pathlib
>>> p = pathlib.Path(".\Gallery")
>>> for img_file in p.rglob("*.jpg"):
...   print(img_file)
...
Gallery\top1.jpg
Gallery\top2.jpg
Gallery\sub1\sub1.jpg
Gallery\sub2\sub2.jpg
Gallery\sub2\sub3.jpg
Gallery\sub3\sub4.jpg
```